# PostgreSQL last full n months

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query with dates for the last two years. I want to get data dynamically for the last 4 months.
That is if today 04/01/2021 I want to get data from 01/09/2020 up today inclusive.
The problem with my query is that I get data between 04/09/2020 up today, i.e. 4 months not including a full first month.
PostgreSQL

```
SELECT     Category,
           Product,
           Sales,
           Date
FROM Table
WHERE Date>= now() - INTERVAL '4 months'
```

What I need to change in my query ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `date_trunc` like following query.

```
        SELECT     Category,
           Product,
           Sales,
           Date
FROM Table
WHERE Date>= date_trunc('month', current_date-interval '4 months')
```